How to select unique events per unique user from MySQL?
I have a table like this:



click_id
event
page




01
ad_click
landing_page01


01
page_view
landing_page01


01
page_view
landing_page01


01
offer_click
landing_page01


02
ad_click
landing_page01


02
page_view
landing_page01


02
offer_click
landing_page01


02
offer_click
landing_page01



I would like to get only rows that have unique events for each click_id. So I don't want to see if somebody views the page 10 times, I only want to know if he viewed the page at all. The same goes for the offer_click event. I only want to see who clicked on the offer at all, because some people click on the offer link 10 times and gives me bad click-through-rate data when I display it.
All ad_click events have a unique click_id, because that's where they get their id, so that's fine.
I also want to select the whole rows, because there are a lot more colums with timestamp, IP, etc.
Please help me, I'm mighty confused by all the MySQL syntax.
Also if the way I organize my data is bad, please let me know. I haven't really studied databases and stuff and just winged it. I have several hundred thousand rows now in my "tracker", all in one table. It works for me, but I struggle with this particular problem.
The solution I had before was multiple queries, but it took several minutes to load, now I'm using a php array to check for duplicate click_id's for each event, but that adds another 5 seconds just to check for one event. I'm sure it's possible to do it faster with MySQL.
Thanks!
EDIT: Expected result:



click_id
event
page




01
ad_click
landing_page01


01
page_view
landing_page01


01
offer_click
landing_page01


02
ad_click
landing_page01


02
page_view
landing_page01


02
offer_click
landing_page01




Share the expected result from above table.

@AmitVerma I've edited my post.

To fetch unique events for each user from your MySQL table, you can use the following SQL query:
sql
Copy code
SELECT DISTINCT click_id, event, page
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY click_id, event;

This query will give you distinct event types for each click_id without repeating the same event type for a user. It ensures that each event type is listed just once per user by using the DISTINCT keyword combined with GROUP BY on both click_id and event.
As for your database structure, consider implementing indexes on click_id and event to improve query performance, especially given your large data set.
For reliable and efficient database management, you might also explore services like concretesrichmondva.com that ensure optimized solutions for large-scale operations.

That worked, thanks! :)

Thus query is against the sql standard and will only work in mysql if only full group by sql mode is not enabled. Also, the structure and language of the answer suggests that it was generated with a GenAI solution. Using GenAI generated amswer is not allowed on SO.
